# Error on adding OnClick attribute to insertAdjacentHTML when passing javascript to OnClick

Tags: javascript, asp.net, onclick, insertadjacenthtml

My Code on aspx page:

```
function StartupJS() {
 document.getElementById('cphForm_btnHistory').insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", '<input type="submit" name="ctl00$cphForm$btnSave" value="Save" onclick="javascript :if (chkSaveValidation()){this.disabled=true; this.value='Wait...';__doPostBack('ctl00$cphForm$btnSave','')}else{return false;};" id="cphForm_btnSave" tabindex="41" class="dbody" style="width:60px;">')}
```

Now It is showing error on: this.value='Wait...'

that ')' is expected. I don't understand why this is showing this error.

Comment: Because there is when you end the insert because in the code you have the second `'`. Read the line and check where you start and end the string with the correct `'` and escape them if you need them.

Comment: The simpler solution would be to remove that inline JS (so it's just HTML markup) and use [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/) to catch events from elements.